# How do I get a for loop to iterate over each word in a list of words in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, loops, for-loop

I am trying to get this loop to capitalize each word using the capitalize() function

Here is the code

```
def cap(words):
  for j in words:
    print(j)
    return j.capitalize()

s = "my name"
parts = s.split(" ")
print(parts)
it = iter(parts)

capped = cap(parts)
print(capped)

result = capped.join(" ")

print(capped)
```

Output:

```
['my', 'name']
my
My
My
```

I am wanting it to return both words capitalized.

Comment: The function `cap` return after the first word. You need to collect the capitalize words in list and return them

Comment: `parts = s.split(" ")` creates a list as you can see by splitting the string. Now just loop over that list: `[w.capitalize() for w in parts]` for a list comprehension or `for i, w in enumerate(parts): parts[i] = w.capitalize()`

Answer (score 1):

What about something as simple as:

```
[s.capitalize() for s in words]
```

What is happening here?

In short, code complexity optimisation.  Rather than writing verbose, (potentially) inefficient code, part of writing quality code is efficiency and readability.

This loop is using a technique called [list comprehension](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3). This is a *very* useful technique when dealing with lists, or for something simple enough to not require a dedicated function.

As `words` is iterated, the `.capitalize()` function is called on each word with the results being appended to the returned list - without explicitly appending the list.

To make this into a function, you can use:

```
def cap(words) -> list:
    """Capitalise each word in a list.

    Args:
        words (list): List of words to be capitalised.

    Returns:
        A list of capitalised words.

    """
    return [s.capitalize() for s in words]
```

Output:

```
words = 'my name'.split(' ')
cap(words)

>>> ['My', 'Name']
```

Comment: in full: `def cap(words): return [s.capitalize() for s in words]`

Answer (score 1):

### Why does the program fail?

Have a closer look at your `cap()` function.

```py
def cap(words):
  for j in words:
    print(j)
    return j.capitalize()
```

`return j.captialize()` will exit the function and will only return the capitalized value of the first word.

### Correction

The function must capitalize all the elements in the list.

```py
def cap(words):
    capitalized = []
    for word in words:
        capitalized.append(word.capitalize())
    return capitalized
```

Now the final code should look like

```py
def cap(words):
    capitalized = []
    for word in words:
        capitalized.append(word.capitalize())
    return capitalized

words = ["hello","foo","bar"]
capitalized = cap(words)

print(*capitalized)
```

perhaps a more *pythonic* way would be to use a list comprehension

```py
def cap(words):
    return [word.capitalize() for word in words]

words = ["hello","foo","bar"]
capitalized = cap(words)

print("Regular: ",*words) # printing un-packed version of words[]
print("Capitalized: ",*capitalized)
```

Output:

> Regular:  hello foo bar 
> Capitalized:  Hello Foo Bar

Answer (score 0):

I have "cleaned" your code (but kept the concept).

Note that it can be done in a much shorter way.

```
def cap(words):
  result = []
  for j in words:
    result.append(j.capitalize())
  return result

words = "my name"
words_lst = words.split(" ")
capped = cap(words_lst)
result = " ".join(capped)
print(result)
```

output

```
My Name
```

A shorter way :-)

```
print(' '.join([s.capitalize() for s in 'my name'.split(' ')]))
```

output

```
My Name
```